# How to close a popup when clicking on another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of buttons that show a popup like a tooltip when clicking on it and closes it when you click again.

I am looking for: when you click one of those button, any popup opened before automatically closes with no need of clicking again on it.

```
function myFunction2() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup2");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
function myFunction3() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup3");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a class (let's call it "*btns*") to all buttons (supposing that you're using the `<button>` tag) and try doing the following :

```
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");

    if (document.querySelectorAll("button.btns").style.display = "block") {
        document.querySelectorAll("button.btns").style.display = "none";
        &&
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
```

Comment: I can't complete your solution. Do you think is something wrong in my code?

This is my button

<button type="button" class="parrafo3" onclick="myFunction()"><span>Introduction</span><span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Description</span></button>


and this is the CSS for "show"

.parrafo3 .show {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.2s;
animation: fadeIn 0.2s;
}

Comment: You're nesting the tooltip inside the `<button>` tag

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do that will be toggling the class on every element(popup) at the same time.

For simplicity, you can also assign the same class to each popup.

example:

```
function myFunction() {
    var popups = document.getElementsByClassName("myPopup");
    for( var i = 0 ; i< popups.length; i++) {
      popups[i].classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

Comment: There’s a typo it should be `popups[i]` instead of `popup[i]`